# How to improve 'Atmospheric scattering sky from space artifacts' question?

Tags: discussion

The [question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/50373/atmospheric-scattering-sky-from-space-artifacts/64260?noredirect=1#64260) seems to attract low-effort answers, which point to sites that I originally used when researching the subject. I've also reviewed the linked source code multiple times against the answers and the outcome has been the same: the artefacts remain.

My feeling is that the question fails to pin-point the problem concisely and therefore distracts people who might be able to answer. How can I improve the question so that it would eventually get answered and my problem would be solved?

Answer (score 3):

My feeling is that the poor answers come down to a few things:

- Complex subject matter that few will be specialized in (physics-based shaders).
- Much effort required to follow up on your research links.
- A lack of focus because many issues were mentioned (two shaders mentioned, fCameraAngle, lack of hue, wrong line positioning, negating the ray, etc).

I suspect you may get better results if the question was very simple and direct, e.g. "I get this screenshot when fCameraAngle = 1, which is correct, and this when fCameraAngle = 0.9, which is not. Note the x, y and z wrong with it. What's going on?".